# Python: Unicode literal functions?

Tags: python, unicode, set, character, literals

Recently I've run into a problem with my script when expanding to non-English languages where accented characters (etc.) would instead display as, for example, `\xe4` when printed or saved to a file.

To tackle this, I came up with a short-term solution of replacing the `"xe4"` with `u"00e4"`. A few more changes later, this little cheat worked but was long, ugly, and required me to define every character as I came across it, and meant I had to reuse the same massive code block of replace lines over and over. This data is also stored in a Tuple which can be semi-problematic at times.

Is there an easy way to future-proof this method? Has anyone written a function or a better way to tackle this problem? My systems runs on Python 2.7.5

Comment: Where are the non-ASCII characters coming from?  In general you want to transform input to Unicode as close to the input source or process as possible, and transform from Unicode to the target encoding during output.  This requires that you know (or control) the encoding used by both your input and output.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example?

Comment: @rd_nielsen The data comes from several MySQL tables. We mix the tables together so the data is relevant and appropriate for the use. As I recall, all the data is in a UTF-8 character set in the tables, then encoded as (I believe) is necessary in a chcp1292 script.

Comment: You should determine definitively what encoding is used in the tables.  The inputs to those tables should also be controlled so that inputs in a variety of encodings are all correctly converted to the database encoding.  (And is  cp1292 correct?--I can't find a reference to that encoding.)

Comment: @rd_nielsen I've mucked with encoding in the tables a fair amount to try and get around this problem, but I'm sure it was UTF-8 the last I checked. Inputting to the table goes through a Python script which I haven't even thought about looking at yet. That could be an idea. And yes, it's chcp/cp/windows1292. That seemed to work best with Amazon and Excel when I was working this out originally.

Comment: This video might give you a leg up [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming UTF-8:

```
print ["る"], type("る")  # ['\xe3\x82\x8b'] <type 'str'>
print ["る".decode("utf-8")], type("る".decode("utf-8"))  # [u'\u308b'] <type 'unicode'>
print [u"る"], type(u"る")  # [u'\u308b'] <type 'unicode'>
```

I think the `\xe4` you're getting is because it is a string and you need to turn it in to unicode.
This is effectively what you were doing when you do that replacement of `"xe4"` with `u"00e4"`.

Comment: My data is pulled from SQL into a Tuple, converted to a string, has all the data cleaned up, replaced with the Unicode characters, then converted back. This fix looks quite easy. Would it work with this really ugly and inefficient system I have in place? If it skips the tuple > string > clean > tuple fiasco that would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Why do you have to convert an entire tuple to a string? What about converting the `tuple` to a `list` (so that it becomes mutable) and then doing `for i in range(0, len(list)): list[i] = list[i].decode("utf-8")` and then turning it back in to a `tuple`

Comment: As mentioned, I had to force a solution. I didn't have much time, so it's very inefficient. .replace requires strings iirc, so yeah. My dumb solution sucks. If your solution works, that would be awesome! I'll definitely try it asap.